# How to update application's version number in control panel

Tags: vb.net

I created an application in VB.NET and installed it by creating a setup routine.

Now I've changed the version number in assembly and updated the .exe file but in control panel it's still showing the old version number.

How can I fix this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/1024664

Comment: What tool / framework did you use to create the setup? This information is created by the setup and needs to be configured somewhere in your setup project.